# Pairwise swapping of rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a device settings table with threshold types and values.
Let's say *ThresholdType = 0 is Min and ThresholdType = 1 is Max*
The initial table looks like this:

```
DeviceID    ThresholdType  ThresholdValue
1           0              5  
1           1              10
2           0              15  
2           1              20
3           0              21  
3           1              34
4           0              1 
4           1              8
```

Then I had to change ThresholdType meaning - *0 became Max threshold and 1 became Min one*.

I want the table look like that:

```
DeviceID    ThresholdType  ThresholdValue
1           0              10  
1           1              5
2           0              20  
2           1              15
3           0              34  
3           1              21
4           0              8 
4           1              1
```

Is it possible to change update it with a single SQL without loops?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `CASE` expresion?

Comment: Are there exactly two `ThresholdType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update ThresholdType instead:

```
update tablename set ThresholdType = 1 - ThresholdType
```

In case other ThresholdType values might show up later, you can add `WHERE ThresholdType IN (1, 2)`, to be a bit safer.

Comment: Obviously you meant to update `ThresholdType`. As noted in other comment - it is far safer to assume the domain of the column is intended to expand (if not already) and filter for only the 2 specific values.

Comment: @SMor, oops, absolutely! Thank you!

Comment: @SMor, I thought about it for a while, but this was so nice and short so I left it out. However, I'll add a note about it.

Answer (score 3):

Just swap the `ThresholdType`:

```sql
UPDATE t SET ThresholdType = CASE ThresholdType
    WHEN 1 THEN 0
    WHEN 0 THEN 1
    ELSE ThresholdType
END
```

Execute the query exactly once.

Comment: A safer approach is to include a WHERE clause that selects rows where ThresholdType is 1 or 0. This will avoid useless updates that change nothing but will still be included in the virtual tables used by any triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
update t
set ThresholdValue = (
  select x.ThresholdValue
  from t x
  where x.DeviceID = t.DeviceID and x.ThresholdType <> t.ThresholdType
)
```

Result:

```
 DeviceID  ThresholdType  ThresholdValue 
 --------- -------------- -------------- 
 1         0              10             
 1         1              5              
 2         0              20             
 2         1              15
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5688b12db308c8f26ed3e3bffc59e142).